# How would you accelerate several clips together in kdenlive?

Tags: video-editing

I use kdenlive to create timelapses of my drawings. Given how I work, I usually have several dozen videos that together sum up 5 to 12 hours or footage and I want to turn them into a single 5 minute clip.

However, I don't know a way to accelerate a single video (let alone a dozen) to a specified duration, and when I try to select them all and change their speed %, it just changes the speed of one of them.

My current workaround involves: Calculating the % of speed I need on a spreadsheet based on the total duration of the clips, duplicate the clips with that %, and then insert those clips.
This is a really cumbersome process. Is there a better way to do it?